# Secure Erase software interchangable when enabling hardware encryption?

Tags: ssd, encryption, secure-erase

I'm trying to Secure Erase a Samsung 850 EVO SSD as part of enabling hardware encryption. Samsung Magician describes having to "ready to enable" it in the Windows software, followed by a Secure Erase of the drive through bootable USB, followed by a clean install of Windows. However, when I try to do the erase, the bootable tool says the drive is in a frozen state and tells me to unplug the power cable for a few seconds. The thing is: it's an m.2 drive, so there are no cables to unplug, and unplugging the entire thing and putting it back in then makes the software not detect it at all. (It's also a precarious process considering the tiny size of the drive and the location of the m.2 slot -- hidden in between the graphics card and CPU cooler.)

My question is this: can I use other software besides Samsung's for this process? And if so: which software can solve or work around this "frozen state" problem?

(Sidenote out of curiosity: what is about the Secure Erase process that enables hardware encryption? Does it flag something on the drive to indicate its readiness?)

Comment: I remember reading about this somewhere... I think secure erase just sets a new encryption key & forgets the old one, effectively the same thing. Some other software could freeze/unfreeze & get things going, if I find it again I'll post something

Comment: I believe the answer to my original question then is: yes, it can be any Secure Erase software, so long as you managed to solve the "frozen state" problem. Apparently, different software offers different solutions. In my specific case, I managed to unfreeze by enabling the hot plug options on the SATA port that is actually the m.2 port. This allowed me to unplug and replug the m.2 drive while having the Secure Erase tool open. I have since successfully Secure Erased the drive. (Now I just wish I could restore my Windows 10 image without losing the hardware encryption capability...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your machine's BIOS is freezing the drive's security settings at boot (to prevent malware from wiping your drive or password-protecting it).

You'll need to disable that feature to be able to continue with the process; it can be re-enabled once you're done.

Edited by OP: If the BIOS doesn't surface such a feature directly, a work-around is to enable hot plug functionality on the SATA port that is the m.2 port, allowing you to unplug and replug the drive during operation, after which the Secure Erase should work. Since the software does nothing more than issue standardized commands like SECURITY_ERASE_UNIT, any Secure Erase software will do so long as you can unfreeze the drive.

Comment: I've gone over the settings available in the UEFI (MSI Z170A Gaming Pro on latest firmware) but I don't see the feature you mention. Is named something specific?

Comment: I don't know what it will be called, but it's a common feature. Read the manual or ask MSI.

Comment: I did read the manual. I don't think the feature is available on this motherboard. However, I managed to circumvent the problem by enabling the hot plug options on the SATA port that is actually the m.2 port. This allowed me to unplug and replug the m.2 drive while having the Secure Erase tool open.

Comment: @Veliremus The cause is the BIOS \[[1](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase#Step_1_-_Make_sure_the_drive_Security_is_not_frozen:), [2](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000006094/memory-and-storage.html)]. If your BIOS doesn't support disabling the SECURITY FREEZE it's performing, then indeed hot-plugging it is the only solution. Since this was indeed the solution, can you upvote and accept this answer?

Comment: Sure, I'll accept the answer, but I'd like to add to your information the actual answer to the original question: that, as far as I can tell, yes, any Secure Erase software will do, but they all require an unfrozen drive. Do you concur?

Comment: Yes, absolutely; [that's the entire point](http://www.admin-magazine.com/Archive/2014/19/Using-the-ATA-security-features-of-modern-hard-disks-and-SSDs) of `SECURITY_FREEZE_LOCK`. The software does nothing more than issue standardized commands like `SECURITY_ERASE_UNIT`.

Comment: Cool, added that information as an edit to your answer and accepted/upvoted it.